# What is the Unix "mailx -t" command equivalent in PowerShell?

Tags: email, unix, powershell

I'm converting some unix scripts to powershell scripts.
I came across the line "mailx -t < d:\mailDetails.txt" in one of the scripts.
mailDetails.txt text file contains the following details.

To:raj123@gmail.com, raj1234@gmail.com
Importance:High
Subject:Testing

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Regards
Raj

In Unix when "mailx -t < d:\mailDetails.txt" is run it will get the details from the text file and mails accordingly.

So in Powershell what is the equivalent of "mailx -t"?

Answer (score 1):

You're a linux guy, right?

```
man mail
```

Which will net you two results:

> Send-MailMessage
>
> Send-FsrmTestEmail

---

We want `Send-MailMessage`....

```
man send-mailmessage
```

Retrieves the following info:

---

### NAME

```
Send-MailMessage
```

### SYNOPSIS

```
Sends an e-mail message.
```

### SYNTAX

```
Send-MailMessage [-To] <String[]> [-Subject] <String> [[-Body] <String>] [[-SmtpServer] <String>] [-Attachments
<String[]>] [-Bcc <String[]>] [-BodyAsHtml] [-Cc <String[]>] [-Credential <PSCredential>]
[-DeliveryNotificationOption <DeliveryNotificationOptions>] [-Encoding <Encoding>] [-Port <Int32>] [-Priority
<MailPriority>] [-UseSsl] -From <String> [<CommonParameters>]
```

### DESCRIPTION

```
The Send-MailMessage cmdlet sends an e-mail message from within Windows PowerShell.
```

### RELATED LINKS

```
Online Version: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135256
```

### REMARKS

```
To see the examples, type: "get-help Send-MailMessage -examples".
For more information, type: "get-help Send-MailMessage -detailed".
For technical information, type: "get-help Send-MailMessage -full".
For online help, type: "get-help Send-MailMessage -online"
```

Comment: Notice that { mailx -t < "d:/mailDetails.txt" }. The mailing details like to recipient mail address, subject and body are taken from text file "mailDetails.txt".

Comment: Yep, the headers are in that file. I understand. There is no equivalent in Powershell. The closest thing you can do, is create a string array out of the mailDetails.txt and then read each line in as a parameter, perhaps with regex. It is much easier to just pass the params directly.

Comment: Can you please post the solution you are telling about?

Answer (score 0):

A 5 second googling tells that `mailx` is a tool for sending mail. Another a 5 second googling tells that `send-mailmessage` is used to send mail.

Comment: Please notice that mailx -t is getting mailing properties like "To adress, importance, subject and body" from the text file "mailDetails.txt".